# optionally apply a filter on dataframe spark/scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a need where I want to filter on a dataframe optionally.

```
def test(df: DataFrame, filterExpr: filter: Option[String] = None) : DataFrame = {
if(filter.isDefined()) df.filter(filterExpr.get) else df
}
```

I don't want to have the if else block outside. Can I apply a filter and let the df take care whether its defined or not?

Comment: Why do you not want to have the `if-else`? To me, it seems the right thing to do here. But you probably should pass `df.filter(filterExpr.get)`, or otherwise access the wrapped value, instead of passing the whole `Option`.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin just checking if there's a better way

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

`filterExpr.map(df.filter).getOrElse(df)`